# Export/fill in with PDF

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way to export a form and have the option of someone filling out the survey through PDF?

Comment: Can export reports to PDF format but filling i am not sure.

Comment: Please have a look at our [help/behavior].

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can create a PDF form but we do not offer the ability to have users fill out the PDF form. We only offer the ability to fill out forms online. If this is a feature you would like to see you can submit a [Feature Request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/featurerequest) so that we can start the evaluation process of creating this at a later date.